Is using two bonds on the same links but with different primaries a terrible idea?
Context: I'm setting up a Proxmox cluster where each node has dual SFP+ NICs. I'm trying to eliminate the network as a single point of failure so that if a switch goes down, the whole cluster doesn't go down. I think the easiest solution would be to set up MLAG, but I'm finding that the switch prices and power consumption aren't practical (plus I already have a few SFP+ switches, they just don't support MLAG).
Proposed Solution: I'm currently thinking that I can divide my network in two, each segment/subnet primarily using one of the links in the NIC, and failing over to the other if a link/switch goes down. The obvious disadvantage is I lose half the theoretical bandwidth when both switches/links are up, but I'm ok with this because proxmox recommends a dedicated 10G+ network for ceph anyways.
Implementation: My plan is to set up two bonds on each node - one using "link 0" as the primary, the other using "link 1". When everything is up, ceph will use one link, all other traffic will use the other. If either goes down, both share a link until everything is restored. The interfaces file looks something like the below. I tested this in a VM, and it seems to work just fine.
Am I missing something? Is this a terrible idea?
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet manual

allow-hotplug ens224
iface ens224 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
        bridge-ports ens192
        bridge-stp enable
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:93
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:94

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
        bridge-ports ens224
        bridge-stp enable
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:95
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:96

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves br0-v0 br1-v0
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-primary br0-v0

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves br1-v1 br0-v1
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-primary br1-v1
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet manual

allow-hotplug ens224
iface ens224 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
        bridge-ports ens192
        bridge-stp enable
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:93
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:94

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
        bridge-ports ens224
        bridge-stp enable
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:95
        address-virtual 00:0c:29:be:48:96

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves br0-v0 br1-v0
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-primary br0-v0

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves br1-v1 br0-v1
        bond-mode active-backup
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-primary br1-v1

--
user@test:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp19s0
23: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:64:8c:83:4e:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::1c64:8cff:fe83:4ee0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
24: br0-v0@br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: br0-v1@br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bond1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
26: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:58:ea:0a:19:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::6058:eaff:fe0a:1986/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: br1-v0@br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
28: br1-v1@br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master bond1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
33: bond1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.7.7.192/24 brd 10.7.7.255 scope global dynamic bond1
       valid_lft 45138sec preferred_lft 45138sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:febe:4896/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:be:48:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.7.7.194/24 brd 10.7.7.255 scope global dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 48026sec preferred_lft 48026sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:febe:4893/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


This is a terrible idea. None of your bonds will ever see that the physical link is down or congested, so it won't be stable. Also, one bond will receive broadcast messages originated at another.
Even if you want to go with two bonds, instead of using bridges to "split NICs in two" (or more), create virtual NICs using SR-IOV (they are called VFs, Virtual Functions) and bond these. This should work better. But it still won't ultimately prevent this scenario which is, I think, the most probable failure mode:

If you're concerned about the cluster resilience, buy proper switches. No way around that. Mikrotik CRS's aren't that expensive and they support MLAG and whatever.
Proxmox's own recommendations are to use 4 or even 6 dedicated NICs: two for cluster communications, two for storage network and two for VM networking.
Another approach could be using a single bond and single bridge, but multiple VLANs, and mstpd, and create two MSTIs, one for CEPH and migration network (e.g. high traffic) to go via one NIC by default, and another for primary cluster ring to ensure lowest delay. Never tried this, though.
Also, Proxmox provides a way to sustain cluster messaging even if one network breaks, and without any bonds: Corosync (which is the base the clustering built upon) allows configuring several rings, so you can assign one NIC to one ring and another to another ring, have two network and the cluster will remain quorate even if one of your networks break.

Thanks for your response. "None of your bonds will ever see that the physical link is down or congested, so it won't be stable." This doesn't seem to be the case. When the physical link goes down, the bridge also goes down. The bonds see the bridge go down, and because they're in active/standby mode, switch to the other bridge. I tested and confirmed this behavior on a stock Debian 12 VM. I didn't check congestion or "soft" downs, but I'll have to see if miimon handles that.


Also, one bond will receive broadcast messages originated at another.

This is desired since they each bond will be a separate subnet.

Interesting point about the failure mode. I did a continuous ping while taking links up and down, and never lost a packet. But that 1s interval is not very fast... I suspect the pinging client gets a destination unreachable and sends a new ARP request when that happens. I'll have to dig into this more.
